# How to use forked jekyll repository

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I forked jekyll and made some changes in my repository. How can I use my forked version of jekyll instead of the main jekyll repository that I used to initially create my blog?

I guess this is more of a general github question than something specific to jekyll.

Thanks, 
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build your modified Jekyll gem:

```
$ gem build jekyll.gemspec
```

Then install it:

```
$ gem install jekyll-0.10.0.gem
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to check to see that my blog is using the forked version?

Comment: When I run $ jekyll --version it just says jekyll 0.10.0

Comment: @Scott: The version will stay the same unless you change it in the gemspec.